# Installing TensorRT gives "Packages File not found" error

Tags: tensorrt

While installing TensorRT, the below error occurred. I have already installed cuda 9.0 and cudnn 7.0.5. How do I avoid this error?

> Err:5 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-0-local Packages File not found - /var/cuda-repo-9-0-local/Packages (2: No such file or directory)

Comment: Thanks，help me correct the grammar mistakes

Comment: I have solved the problem, just delete the file named dpkg -P nv-tensorrt-repo-ubuntu1604-cuda9.0-ga-trt4.0.1.6-20180612, and it's ok